# Execute statement after animation is done

Tags: java, android, animation, execute

What I am trying to do is make the `ImageView` shake at button press, and when the animation is over, the image from `ImageView` disappears.

I want this statement to execute first:

```
ObjectAnimator
                .ofFloat(img, "translationX", 0, 25, -25, 25, -25, 15, -15,     6, -6, 0)
                .setDuration(300)
                .start();
```

and after the animation is over, this statement should execute:

```
        img.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

I have them one after another, so the animation doesn't end the pictures are gone.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code,

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img, "translationX", 0, 25, -25, 25, -25, 15, -15,     6, -6, 0).addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                Log.e("Animation-Completed:", "onAnimationEnd");
                img.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            }
        }).setDuration(300).start();
```

**Edit:** to add duration:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img, "translationX", 0, 25, -25, 25, -25, 15, -15,     6, -6, 0);
anim.setDuration(300);                  // Duration in milliseconds
anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    Log.e("Animation-Completed:", "onAnimationEnd");
                    img.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                }
            }); 
anim.start();
```

Comment: I get an error `Variable 'img' is accessed from within inner class, and needs to be declared final`.

Comment: :) @Eddie just follow the error and add the `final` keyword before the declaration of the `img` variable like below, `final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.some_id);`

Comment: Can I still change it's properties, if its declared final?

Comment: I do get another error. `cannot find symbol 'setDuration'`

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code:

```
ObjectAnimator
            .ofFloat(img, "translationX", 0, 25, -25, 25, -25, 15, -15,     6, -6, 0)
            .setDuration(300)
            .start()
            .addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                   img.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                }
            });
```